# Migrating from JDBC into JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, frameworks, persistence

My question is how I can migrate my JDBC Project into JPA.  My project is totally built using JDBC and has already had many methods created.  EclipseLink, Hibernate any JPA framework is welcome. But in order to perform this migration, we need to know if there is any tool that can help in converting a JDBC Project into JPA and we do not have to code the logic again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically - you can't. JPA is a totally and completely different thing working on object model hierarchies. Migrating from JDBC to JPA means rewriting and rethinking your entire data model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comment that this might be hard. How hard depends on how your project is coded, parameters such as how separated the business logic is from the DAO layer. This has done before, and is of course possible. Wether it's worth the cost or not is up to you.

However, to help answer your question, yes there are tools to help with this. Hibernate comes with [reverse engineering](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#reverseengineering) functionality meaning you can create `Entity` objects from the database schema.

This will create `Entities` for you, then it's up to you to replace the DAO layer.